# Create migration in Laravel with and without prefix

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, eloquent

I need to create a database that has ALMOST all tables with a prefix, but some tables can't have it (legacy tables used in other softwares).

So, let's say I have 3 tables:

- user
- group
- person

user is a legacy table, so the nomenclature should be

- user
- myprefix_group
- myprefix_person

I added the prefix in the `App/Config/Database.php` and `App/Config/Local/Database.php`. The database is in MySql.

Comment: I guess that if you use a `prefix` on your configuration, even that if you somehow disable it and create your table, you'll have trouble with Eloquent trying to find your tables. So I guess that you'll have to manually prefix it. (but I can be wrong, I'll make some tests/research)

Comment: @Ravan Eeyup. this is my main problem... but the models are the ones that are used in the eloquent, if I find a way to disable it on the migration AND in the model. I'm done with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you must do it manually. Just create migrations with prefixes and then add in your models

```
protected $table = 'table_name';
```